# Screenshot grabbing of widget is not working for new Microsoft Office versions

Tags: c++, qt, ms-word, screenshot, clipboard

I have a little piece of code which allowes me to make a screenshot of a single widget in my Qt Application. For YEARS my code has worked fine for Paint and Microsoft Office 2013, at least until I downloaded Office 2016. Since then the screenshot code is not working properly anymore.

When I execute this code (by pressing a button), the image is created, and everything works fine in Paint. But when I try to paste it in MS Office Word 2016, nothing happenes. The Image was put into place by pressing CTRL+V, just like if you pasted some text snippet.

This is my code:

```
QPixmap shot(tableView->grab());
QImage ishot = shot.toImage();
QApplication::clipboard()->setImage(ishot, QClipboard::Clipboard);
```

The tableView Object is completely fine, I already searched there, found nothing. I really don't know where to start fixing this, because I don't even get an error ore something like that. Please tell me why the paste stuff doesn't work anymore or how to change my code so it works again.

**Edit**:

Some poor guy posted the same question ten years ago, he never got an answer...  [Here](http://www.qtforum.org/article/19592/qimage-to-clipboard-some-question-about-it.html?s=0aa8cfd8ba0fc842089ad56b324d62d55f96149f#post74250)

Comment: Can you paste the image to other applications? If it works on paint, it's most likely an error of MS Office. You can try a clipboard viewer to check whats actually copied to the clipboard (like http://www.freeclipboardviewer.com/)

Comment: Yes I can! I can perfectly fine paste it into Paint and other programs like Gimp

Comment: If you paste to paint, and the copy **from paint** and paste in MS Office - is that possible?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is...

Comment: Then it's most likely a format error. Try using a clipboard viewer to find out the differences (Qt provides the image in multiple formats). You may have to convert the image to a native one and use the native clipboard. Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwinmime.html to achieve this.